Is Marginalizing in the Condition Legal?
In this video, the professor writes...$$\Pr(y\ |\ x\ \cap\ \vec D) = \int_\vec w \Pr(y\ |\ x\ \cap\ \vec D\ \cap\ \vec w)\ d\vec w = \int_\vec w \Pr(y\ |\ x\ \cap\ \vec w)\Pr(\vec w\ |\ \vec D)\ d\vec w$$Neither step seems obvious to me, but the first step seems outright wrong.  My argument against the first step focuses on the case in which $\vec w$ is $1$-dimensional.  Suppose we put the Venn diagram which is the universe of these probabilities into an image editor, crop out everything except $x\ \cap\ \vec D$, and save just $x\ \cap\ \vec D$ calling it our new universe.  In our new universe, the claim is...$$\Pr(y) = \int_w \Pr(y\ |\ w)\ dw$$  But this is a density function factor short of being the law of total probability.  The discrete version is also obviously false;$$\Pr(\text{Kelly will go swimming tomorrow}\ |\ \text{it rains}) + \Pr(\text{Kelly will go swimming tomorrow}\ |\ \text{it does not rain})$$need not sum to $1$ and is therefore not equal to $$\Pr(\text{Kelly will go swimming tomorrow})$$
Is this a mistake in the lecture or my reasoning?  Is the statement true somehow if we omit the middle step?

I think the video is a bit wrong. The correct formula should be:
$$
    \text{Pr}(y \vert x, D) = \int \text{Pr}(y, w \vert x, D)dw = \int \text{Pr}(y \vert x, w)\text{Pr}(w \vert D)dw
$$
This is just a (confusing) way to write the following formula
$$
   f_Y(y) = \int f_{X,Y}(x, y)dx = \int f_X(x)f_{Y \vert X}(y \vert x)dx
$$
where $f_X, f_Y$ are marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$, $f_{X, Y}$ is the joint density of the random vector $(X, Y)$ and $f_{Y \vert X}$ is the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$
